# Need to know if assigning variable in Scala future iteration is correct

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Given the following Scala code:

```
object TestFutures6 extends App {

  val f0 = Future { 0 }
  val f1 = Future { 1 }
  val f2 = Future { 2 }
  val fx = Seq(f0,f1,f2)

  var x: String = _
  println("x="+x)

  fx.map { 
    seq => seq.map { i =>
        println("i="+i)
        if (x == null) {
           x = "abc"
           println("x="+x)
        }

    }
  }


  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

I need to know if assigning "abc" to variable `x` is subject to a run condition, as the iterations in `seq.map` may run in parallel. When I run the code I only get "abc" printed once, but I'm wondering if there may be a problem.

Also, I need to run this code in Play with the following context

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is technically a potential race condition here, though it may never actually occur.

Essentially you are relying on the fact that these two lines will never be "interleaved" among different threads:

```
    if (x == null) {
       x = "abc"
```

If two threads execute the null check before either executes setting x to abc, then they will both enter that block.

That might not happen in this toy example since your futures are quite simple and just complete immediately, but this is very bad practice and should not be in any production code.

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly not thread safe, and in general the behavior would be non-deterministic.  You may not see an issue when you run it, but we don't know what execution context you're using.

In general threads and statefulness don't go together.  If you must have mutable state use a library/technique designed for statefulness (e.g. actors).